# Error getting html content from another domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I want to get a text from another domain using javascript or PHP. However, it gives me an error while trying to access another domain. I tried this piece of code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.corsproxy.com/' +
        'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Briarcliff_Manor,_New_York',
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data){
           $('#content').html($(data).find('#firstHeading').html());
        }
});
```

and the error is

has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Is there anyway that I can grab the content of the html for another domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per browser's Single origin policy, it will not allow to read the other domains response, there server needs to add header for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to allow it read by browser for your domain.

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses
>   additional HTTP headers to let a user agent gain permission to access
>   selected resources from a server on a different origin (domain) than
>   the site currently in use. A user agent makes a cross-origin HTTP
>   request when it requests a resource from a different domain, protocol,
>   or port than the one from which the current document originated.

ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS